# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a 10-period Exponential Moving Average for stock prices. i.e. calculating average of last 10 stock prices.

To achieve this I wrote a function, but it is giving most unexpected of errors.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def calc_ema(prices, window, smoothing=2):
    ema = [sum(prices[:window])/window]
    for price in prices[window:]:
        ema.append((price*(smoothing/(1+window)))+ema[-1]*(1-(smoothing/(1+window))))
        return ema
   
data = {'Price':[120, 100, 108, 112, 109, 131, 125, 122, 115, 119, 124, 137, 141, 139, 136]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

Dema = calc_ema(df,10)
print (Dema)
```

When the execution goes to:

```
ema = [sum(prices[:window])/window]
```

It gives error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `prices` to `prices.loc[:, 'Price']` solves the issue:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def calc_ema(prices, window, smoothing=2):
    ema = [sum(prices.loc[:, 'Price'][:window])/window]
    for price in prices.loc[:, 'Price'][window:]:
        ema.append((price*(smoothing/(1+window)))+ema[-1]*(1-(smoothing/(1+window))))
        return ema
   
data = {'Price':[120, 100, 108, 112, 109, 131, 125, 122, 115, 119, 124, 137, 141, 139, 136]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

Dema = calc_ema(df,10)
print (Dema)
```

Output:

```
[116.1, 117.53636363636363]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try passing `df['Price']` as an argument instead of `df`:

```py
Dema = calc_ema(df['Price'],10)
```